# Import number format from SAP in Microsoft Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, sap

I would like to know if there is a method of extract 1234.00 from this comma separated number 1,234.00 which I imported from SAP.  Excel does not recognise the format which this cell is formatted in, thus no calculation can be done using this number.

Comment: Have you tried changing the cell properties to format the cell as a number? Double-checked that there are no leading/trailing whitespace characters?

Answer (score 0):

If the cells are correct (i.e. "1,234.00" is in a single cell and not split across two cells), and assuming it's formatted as General, you should simply be able to do a Replace All to remove the commas:

- Highlight the column or columns in question
- Open the Replace dialog
- Put a single comma in the "Find what:" box and leave the "Replace with:" box empty
- Press Replace All.

Excel will now be able to interpret this as a number.